# Import an edge list in csv format. and plot a graph for the complete edgelist

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j

I have a data set in the form of a edgelist as :
[Click to see sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dz9A.png)

I want to load this csv into neo4j and create a one-to-one relationship between A and P, A and Q and so on, and represent it graphically.

How can i do that using neo4j? 
I am only able to import the file and not able to create any relationship

Comment: As Max mentioned, you've provided very little info here. You've referenced some things (A and P, A and Q, columns a and a1 in your edge list) with virtually no context as to what any of these are or mean. We can infer that A, P, and Q are nodes. We can guess that the A column in your edge list refers to an A node. But we have no idea what a1 is (another node id? a property on an A node?), or how it relates the the other nodes you listed, or what these nodes represent, what labels you want to use, what relationship types you want to use, and so on. Give us more context please!

Answer (score 0):

There is very  little information to go on here. If you are using LOAD CSV to import then post what you have tried.  If all you have is an edge list, you need to create the nodes that do not exist already in the database. So use a MERGE command on the node identifier to use it if it exists or create it if it doesn't.